# How to create a custom Expandable list with Image text and group indicator in the right?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am creating an Expandable List view in android. I have a query of how to can i set the layout of the expandable list view having the Image on the left text on the center and the group indicator on the right. [image: How to make the group indicator appear in a proper manner?]

If you see the image the group indicator is getting squashed i want it to appear in a normal way. How can i do so?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#67B1E2">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/homescreen_left_btn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/firstedittext"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/user_btn"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:clickable="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>

     <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#556268"/>  

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/home_screen_linear_join_event"
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/join_event_btn"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:clickable="true">

       <ImageView 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/join_event_icn"
           android:layout_gravity="left|center"/>

     <Button
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:text="Join an Event"
         android:textColor="#4F4F4F"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
     </LinearLayout>

      <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#76B8E5"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

     <ExpandableListView
       android:id="@+id/expandablelistview01"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
       android:childDivider="#94bdd8"
       android:divider="#94bdd8"
       android:dividerHeight="1dp"
       android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
       android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
       android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
       android:listSelector="@android:color/white"
       android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
   </ExpandableListView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please update the question with your xml code.

Comment: Hello Sankar V i have uploaded the xml code